# #1406 - Data too long for column 'producto' at row 1

Tags: mysql

Se que este error ya ha sido tratado en otros hilos pero ninguno de ellos ha solucionado mi problema

Tengo un campo en mi tabla que se llama producto, este campo es de tipo Varchar(255) y al hacer cualquier actualización del campo con mas de 20 caracteres me salta el error.

el campo: [image: campo producto]

La consulta:  `UPDATE info_test SET producto="supermercadopatatasfritas" WHERE linea=4`

He probado desactivando el modo estricto, he cambiado el tipo de campo a longtext y siempre falla tanto haciendo el update desde una aplicacion como haciendolo de forma manual desde phpmyadmin.

La Base de Daros se encuentra en una Raspberry con raspbian.

Un saludo

Comment: ¿Probaste añadiendo el nombre de la base de datos?

Comment: No, ¿Cómo se especifica la base de datos a una consulta Update?

Comment: Anteponiéndolo al nombre de la tabla: `base.tabla`

Comment: Probado y sigue el mismo error

Comment: Que versión de MySQL estas utilizando?

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.27-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnueabihf (armv8l) using readline 5.2

Comment: Sólo para corroborar: ¿`DESC base.tabla` indica 255?

Comment: Si, el campo indica 255 al hacer DESC

Comment: ¿Tiene triggers la tabla?

Comment: No hay Trigger en la tabla